# Appium - Install iOS apps from a testflight public url

Tags: appium, appium-ios, testflight-public-link

I'm trying to install / run an iOS app from a test flight public url when using appium desktop but get the following error when starting the session:

"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not install app: 'ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir '/var/folders/[DIRECTORY_PATH]/[RANDOM_GENERATED_CODE].app''"

The desired capabilities I provided to appium desktop are shown below:

```
{
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "[DEVICE_NAME]",
  "platformVersion": "13.3",
  "xcodeOrgId": "[XCODE_ORG_ID]",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
  "udid": "[DEVICE_UDID]",
  "bundleId": "[APP_BUNDLE_ID]",
  "updatedWDABundleId": "[WEDRIVER_AGENT_RUNNER]",
  "app": "https://testflight.apple.com/join/[RANDOM_GENERATED_CODE]"
}
```

Does appium support this functionality? If so what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to download the app before setting up Appium. (with bash script or Java itself)

After downloading, set the local URL in the capabilities.

Comment: I'm currently doing that with the enterprise app but the problem i'm facing is I have to manually trust the app once it's installed; i thought if i use a test flight public url I could install the app and bypass the manual trusting process.

Comment: Do you use real devices?

Comment: Yep. For now, i've automated part of test flight to install the app and then I run the automation.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
install app: 'ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir '/var/folders/[DIRECTORY_PATH]/[RANDOM_GENERATED_CODE].app''"
```

Seems to indicate you are pointing to a file, not a directory, which is what the executing code expected. Are you supposed to expand the artifacts from TestFlight before using them? Perhaps something is wrong with the `[DirectoryPath]` you specified. What's actually at that location after the failure occurs?

Comment: According to the app desired capability (http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities) It doesn't look like you need to do any preliminary setup before calling the url. The only thing i can think of is it only accepts http and not https urls? As for the directory location it generated an app file at the directory location with a file name of [RANDOM_GENERATED_CODE].app but when you look at the file size it's no way near the size it should be.